# Similar functionality in SSJS equalent to textContent?

Tags: javascript, xpages

```
<p id="test"> Hello </p>
```

How can I get the `Hello` with the use of SSJS in XPages?

Comment: document.getElementById("test").textContent will return Hello. But in SSJS I am not able to get the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do that in the manner in which you are thinking. XPages, more specifically XSP, where you enter the HTML code you outlined above is actually an XML representation of java code that is created on the back end. In fact, the Hello text is actually converted to a component of type UIPassThroughText. To get it you would have to get the component representing the p tag, then iterate through the child nodes, checking the type and then content of the child nodes until you found the one you wanted. BUT, this really is not what you want to do. If you want to dynamically get or set the inner value of a node, you need to use something like a xp:text tag, and in that tag reference a scoped variable or some other form of persistant data storage to set the value.

Answer (score 4):

SSJS is used in conjunction with XPages controls, if you are outputting raw HTML and not XPages controls I would imagine this would be very difficult if at all possible.

In SSJS you can query for XPAges controls by using:

```
getComponent(' <controlId> ');
```

and get its value with:

```
getComponent(' <controlId> ').getValue();
```

I would suggest trying to use an XPages control such as:

```
<xp:label></xp:label>   or   <xp:inputText></inputText>
```

There are ways to do the reverse meaning executing server side on client side such as:

```
var clientVariable = #{javascript:sessionScope.variable}
```